# Word order when addressing someone

Tags: forms-of-address

When I want to adress someone, is it correct to put one's name at the beginning or at the end of the sentence? On different forums when I need to thank someone, what is the best way to say:

> Thank you for your answer, Sandy!

or

> Sandy, thank you for your answer!

Which is more correct?

Answer (score 3):

The first version is definitely more natural when you are speaking.

However, in writing, and especially on a forum or in a chat room, in order to make sure the addressed person actually *sees* you are addressing them, it is quite common to move their name (or nick name) to the front, often preceded by an @-sign. (In SE chat rooms, this will cause a signal to be sent to the person you mention to draw their attention.)

When someone "scans" or quickly reads over new posts or reactions, their name will stand out and it will be clear that they are being addressed.

Comment: I'd say that the second is probably much more common anytime that you want to pick a particular person out of a group, not just when writing online; if you are in a team meeting, for example, or on a conference call.